# Call stored procedure from c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

I created a test application with Thread and call stored procedure. If I call stored procedure from console application stored procedure executes, but does not insert values into test table. I'm using a `DbContext`. If I call procedure in SQL Server Management Studio then value adds to test table. Where is error?

My console application for thread call stored procedure:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
             ModelContext context = new ModelContext();
             Thread t = new Thread(() => ThreadTestProcedure(context));
             t.Start();
    }
```

Thread call method:

```
 private static void ThreadTestProcedure(ModelContext сontext)
            {
                try
                {                
                        context.RunTestProcedure(1000, "Test")
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

My stored procedure for insert values to test table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure
   @Int1 INT,
   @SrtingValue nvarchar(250)
AS        
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
                   WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ASSIGNMENTS_DELETED]') 
                   AND type in (N'U'))
   BEGIN
      CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENTS_DELETED
             (ID INT PRIMARY KEY (ID) identity(1,1),
              Assigment int, 
              StringValue nvarchar(250)
             )   
   END 

   WHILE 1=1 
   BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
          insert into ASSIGNMENTS_DELETED
             select @Int1, @SrtingValue            

          COMMIT TRANSACTION
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
          IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
          RAISERROR ('it broke', 16, 1)
     END CATCH
 END
```

Comment: Hope it helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Comment: I'm also  Map Stored Procedures and call stored procedure with: context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("exec TestProcedure @id, @value", id, value),
new SqlParameter("id", id), new SqlParameter("value", value)); But also not insert values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stored procedure has an infinite loop  WHILE 1=1 ??? remove that.

Comment: I need long time execute stored procedure

Comment: It's going to be a real long time.... Why not use a loop instead and you can adjust how long it runs WHILE (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [dbo].[ASSIGNMENTS_DELETED]) < 1000

Answer (score 2):

Remove `WHILE 1=1` from your stored procedure. It goes in **infinite** loop.